# Calculate and print daily total and average for each server array

Tags: python, arrays, variable-assignment

python beginner and needing help with assignment.

Any pointers and code would be appreciated.
Problem is as follows:
Your organization has three network servers that report daily connection statistics on access time. The data was captured 5 times daily for each day for each server.  For each server, you will need to input today's data into 3 different parallel arrays (one for each server) with the access times for each. You will then need to total and average these values for each server.

- Allow user to enter 5 entries in each of three servers' arrays.
- Once the user has entered the daily values, use a  loop to read
  values to total and average access time for each server
- Calculate and print daily total and average for each server array.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to take in user input, of which I am assuming your teacher wants you to read input from a command line.

`user_input = input("Enter a value: ")` will prompt the user to enter a value into the command line.

You can use a dictionary to store values for each of the servers - something like:

`servers = {"server1": [], "server2": [], "server3": []}` will allow you to have a single variable to hold data for each server.

You can access said data like so:

`servers["server1"]` will return your list - in this case its empty, so `[]`

To add data to a list you can use `[].append("data to add")`, so to add data to that dictionary, it'd look like `servers["server1"].append("data to add")`.

If you want to treat "server1", "server2", "server3" as variables, you can just iterate over them in a loop... that would look like this:

```
for server in servers:
    servers[server].append("data to append")
    # this will output the data in the array for each "server#"
    print(servers[server])
```

If you want a traditional for loop - too bad :P! :

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
```

You can access items of an array by using its index, provided that there is an item with that index:

```
arr = ["potato", "banana"]
print(arr[0])
# will print "potato"
print(arr[1])
# will print "banana"
print(arr[2])
# will throw an error, because it doesn't exist in arr
```

With this information, it should be enough to piece it all together.

```
servers variable
for each server in servers:
    for number of times to prompt user:
        servers[each server].append(input(prompt the user for data to append))

use the same loops to sum then average for each array
```